# Benefit of $snapshot with Mongo? Is it okay to disable by default?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, mongomapper

[This Mongo page](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/snapshot/) explains what the $snapshop command does, but can someone explain why this would be helpful, or whether it's wise to disable by default?

We're using MongoMapper on Rails 3.2.12, and MM seems to enable snapshot on every query.

Comment: The page says it prevents the same document being returned twice, which could otherwise happen when there are concurrent updates (and can still happen when you use sharding). Isn't that a helpful assurance?

Comment: It is, but other SO users have suggested turning off $snapshot for performance reasons if "safe." From this, we should assume that if there is the possibility of a document being written and read in parallel, then we should not turn off $snapshot? Or, more precisely, what's the worst case? That one user gets a stale document? (That would be fine in our particular case.)

Answer (score 1):

> From this, we should assume that if there is the possibility of a document being written and read in parallel, then we should not turn off $snapshot? Or, more precisely, what's the worst case? That one user gets a stale document?

No. Not a stale document. But possibly the same document twice, before the update was applied (not stale at that time) and after the update was applied.

This would only happen if the update changes the size of the document, so that it has to be moved physically in the storage location. It does not happen for in-place updates. It could happen if you push something big into an array.

Also note that depending on how you look at this, you may call that first version of the document "stale" (at the time the query finished), but the same applies for all other documents as well: You get the version that was accurate at the time this individual document was pulled by your query. Not necessarily globally consistent across the whole query.

And finally, even with $snapshot on, you still have no guarantee to not get deleted documents and to get all freshly inserted documents. And apparently, it does not work with sharding either.

On the plus side, the documents you get (with snapshot on or off) are always internally consistent: You always get a version that existed at one time, not a weird state in the middle of an update.

> Let's say one query returns a user and all his associated widgets. By disabling $snapshot, this same query will return the player document twice ... meaning the return array could contain two objects instead of one?

The same query cannot return "a user and all his widgets" if they are stored in two collections. There are no joins in MongoDB.

If the widgets are embedded into the user object, then they will be returned together with the user, and always represent a consistent combination.

What could happen here is that if you query a list of all users who have widgets A or Z, and you updated a user that has widget A to also have widget Z (and this moves the document, because it has grown now) you could get the user with widget A, and then a second time with widget A and Z.

If you turn on snapshotting, that won't happen (unless you are using sharding, where snapshots apparently don't work). But you can still get a user that is concurrently being deleted, or not get all users that are being inserted while the query is running.

Comment: Thanks, but what does it mean to get the same document twice? Let's say one query returns a user and all his associated widgets. By disabling $snapshot, this same query will return the player document twice ... meaning the return array could contain two objects instead of one? Sorry if we're still confused ... thanks for your help, though.

Comment: Yes, I meant the user document contains the widgets embedded. To clarify the question, we don't return a list of all users. We only ask for the details for one user at a time (when they log in essentially). Would disabling $snapshot mean the query would return potentially two users? We also observed that $snapshot only seems invoked on the getmore command, which we're not doing directly.

Comment: please note that this duplicate document would not *always* happen if you are updating documents and they are being relocated.  It would only happen if you are updating, documents are moving, and no index is being used for query or an index is being used that is involved in the modified value.  If you are using an index and the modification doesn't change the value that's indexed then you won't get a duplicate (that's what $snapshot does by walking the _id index).

Answer (score 0):

Scanning the MongoMapper and MongoClient code it looks like $snapshot is off by default.  Inspect your code for it being passed as an option to a query somewhere.